# Sorting NSMutableArray with NSDictionaries that contains Numbers as String?

Tags: arrays, xcode, sorting

Have a little Problem and can´t find a working solution :(

I have a NSMutableArray like:

```
{
    Entfernung = 129521;
    "Event_DATE" = "2014-03-23";
    "Event_ID" = 1;
    "Event_KAT" = 1;
    "Event_NAME" = achtzehn;
},
{
    Entfernung = 112143;
    "Event_DATE" = "2014-03-24";
    "Event_ID" = 2;
    "Event_KAT" = 2;
    "Event_NAME" = neunzehn;
}
```

How can i sort this Array with the object "Entfernung"?

Thx 4 help!
Gerhard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this;

```
NSArray *stuff = .... //your array here;

NSSortDescriptor *sorter = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Entfernung" ascending:YES comparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {

    //depending on the number stored in the string, you might need the floatValue or doubleValue instead
    NSNumber *num1 = @([(NSString*)obj1 integerValue]);
    NSNumber *num2 = @([(NSString*)obj2 integerValue]);

    return [num1 compare:num2];
}];

NSArray *sortedStuff = [[stuff sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sorter]];
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest I'd say would be to define a compare method on `Entfernung` class and then use `- (void)sortUsingSelector:(SEL)comparator` If you already have a function which accepts two objects (say your `NSDictionary` object) then I'd do the sort like this `- (void)sortUsingFunction:(NSInteger (*)(id, id, void *))compare context:(void *)context`

Answer (score 0):

Give a man a fish, and he can eat today. Tell him how to fish, and he has to do the work himself for the rest of his life...

In Xcode, look at the help menu. In the help menu, you find an item "Documentation and API reference". There you type in "NSMutableArray", then you search for "sort". Which gives you five methods:

```
– sortUsingDescriptors:
– sortUsingComparator:
– sortWithOptions:usingComparator:
– sortUsingFunction:context:
– sortUsingSelector:
```

You can click on each one and read the description. The most straightforward to use is sortUsingComparator: which comes with a nice bit of sample code that you adapt for your purposes.

Comment: i know this words... but i tried a lot of solutions an the more i try and read the more confused i´m about it... don´t forget pls: i´m austrian, and everything that is about good coding is in english... but thx for your helping

Comment: my problem is: in my understanding i have a array with dictionaries in it, and every dictionary has objects, ... or is this wrong?